# Excel Consecutive Days with at least 60 minutes worked

Tags: excel

[image]

I have project worksheet. Each day I track how many minutes I work on different tasks.

How could I create a formula that counts the number of consecutive days where the total minutes is greater than 60?

The part the part I"m stuck on is the consecutive days part.

I believe this is possible but could someone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: Are you willing to put in a helper column?   If so, `C4` would be `=if( B4 < 60, 0, C3+1)` and copy down.  `B1` would then `=Max(C:C)`

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can achieve this directly:

```
=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(B4:B10>=60,ROW(B4:B10)),IF(B4:B10<60,ROW(B4:B10))))
```

Paste the formula on `B1` in your case and press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` (not just `ENTER`). You will see an array (curly braces like this `{}` will appear before and after the formula automatically once you press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`)

I'm assuming you want to include `60` also. Feel free to modify accordingly.

**Note:** Update the range as you require.

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is more complicated than it looks at first. The following formula could give a correct result:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((B2:B8>=60)+(B2:B8<60)*(B4:B10>=60))*(B3:B9>=60))
```

[image]